# WCF Validation - Requiring and validating custom values

Tags: c#, wcf, validation, soap

We are currently developing some new systems to replace parts of several legacy systems.

We have some new WCF web services which will sit alongside existing ASMX web services.

The ASMX web services authenticate via a Soap Header Context object with 4 custom properties including a token (previously generated and returned at login) which are then validated.

We are not re-writing the validation code yet and the login is still being handled by the existing ASMX services, so we are required to call the existing validator passing in a Context object with the 4 properties from the WCF service application.

How do we capture the 4 properties via the WCF service?

A previous WCF project implemented WCFExtras+ to replicate the Soap Header over WCF.

We can do that again but would prefer a native WCF approach.

I have found options such as custom UserNamePasswordValidator or ServiceAuthorizationManager but have been unable to determine how to exactly apply these to our specific requirements.

Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much googling I wrote my own custom behaviour using IOperationBehavior, IContractBehavior and IDispatchMessageInspector